# Why javascript prototype syntax is so weird?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I learning lot of javascript stuff. I'm not understand what this syntax mean

```
Array.from(obj[, mapFn, thisArg])
```

You see that in first parameter
`obj[`
What is mean?

Why this square bracket started?

Comment: That's *documentation convention*, not Javascript syntax

Comment: The function `from` on object `Array` has three parameters. The 2nd and 3rd parameters are optional.

Comment: Thank you now I understood. Thank you for helping me.